# Can't write image data to path laravel live project

Tags: image, laravel, upload

On my project the user is able to upload a profile picture, and if they don't there is a default picture.  I am using this on my Laravel project, and works 100%.  Now I have hosted my project online it wont allow me to upload a profile picture but picks up the default image.  I'm not sure why.  The error message i'm getting is:

> Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException Can't write image data to path (/home/n1huer/laravel/public/uploads/avatars/1525256072.png)

[This is my file structure within laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoxE5.png)

My controller for this is

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename) );

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();
        
    }
    return view('myaccount', array('user' => Auth::user()) );
}
```

The file path must be right if it is picking up the default?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to make '/uploads/avatars/' writable as the error is saying that it isn't writable.

Log into the remote server (or use a control panel) and change the permissions to the folder you're trying to write to:

```
chmod 755 /home/n1huer/laravel/public/uploads/avatars
```

---

On a side note,
I would look further into public folders and permissions.:

Here is some good advice:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/650241

Also, check out the official docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem

Comment: do i do that in terminal? then will work when i host it again?

Comment: you will need to change permissions on the remote machine

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the command

`sudo chmod -R a+rwx /path/to/folder`

to give permissions to a folder and every file and folder inside it. Omit the `x` from either command if you don't want the files to be executable.

feast your soul [here](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/give-permissions-ubuntu-33174.html)

Happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

### For whom this problem occurs:

First you need to know why this problem occurs

## - See this path

```
path (/home/n1huer/laravel/public/uploads/avatars/1525256072.png)
```

*This path is considered this way*

```
http://myname.com/home/n1huer/laravel/public/uploads/avatars/1525256072.png
```

*But it is intended here to be the actual in this*

```
http://myname.com/uploads/avatars/1525256072.png
```

That is why the problem with the mentioned message occurs

to solve this problem, all you have to do is complete the following

**come on this part**

> ->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename) )

**and replace it with this code to become like this**

> ->save('./uploads/avatars/' . $filename)

and thus the problem is solved without the need to do anything else that may leave another problem leaving it

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem while using Image intervention library. It was working well in my local machine but in aws ubunto machine its giving this error. I have tried in many ways but finally I determined this all about permission issue. I'm using below codes to save an image from `$request` then resize it and then save it in `profile` folder under `public` directory.

```
$img=Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300);
$img->save(public_path('profile/' .$file_storage_name));
```

what I see in my `aws` my `profile` folder is owned and grouped by `root` user. So I changed the ownership using `sudo chown -R 1000:1000 profile` and then changed the group using `sudo chgrp www-data profile` then give the folder read, write and execute permission using `chmod 775  profile` .Then magic ,it work .It look like below image
[image]